# Woocommerce: When i post this script in the functions.php file it points to error, can you see whats wrong?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When i post this script in the functions.php file it points to error, can you see whats wrong?

```js
<?php if(is_product()) {?>
<script>
analytics.track('Product Viewed', {
  'ecommerce': {
    'detail': {
      'products': [{
        'name': '<?php echo the_title(); ?>',
        'id': '<?php echo the_ID(); ?>',
        'brand': 'test',
      'category':'test'
       }]
     }
   }
});
</script>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: are you using any hook for this code?. if no you have to use some hook.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: Its just 500 error when your functions file get messed up. I am not using any hook. What hook should i use?

Comment: I tried with hooks but it still does not work.

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'segment_product_viewed');
 function segment_product_viewed() {
if ( is_product() ) {
<script>
analytics.track('Product Viewed', {
  'ecommerce': {
    'detail': {
      'products': [{
        'name': 'echo the_title();',
        'id': 'echo the_ID();',
        'brand': 'test',
      'category':'test'
       }]
     }
   }
});
</script>
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Getting 500 error? seems there's a Fatal error and some servers simply return 500 for PHP fatal errors.

Look at your code. remove first opening and last closing PHP tags.

Your code should looks like below. also if there's nothing in Functions.php file then you have to add opening PHP tag.

```
if(is_product()) {?>
<script>
analytics.track('Product Viewed', {
  'ecommerce': {
    'detail': {
      'products': [{
        'name': '<?php echo the_title(); ?>',
        'id': '<?php echo the_ID(); ?>',
        'brand': 'test',
      'category':'test'
       }]
     }
   }
});
</script>
<?php }
```